# Looking for a ASP.NET and ACCESS based Wiki

Tags: .net, asp.net, wiki

I want to establish a simple and slim ASP.NET based Wiki, which can be used with ACCESS. What do you can recommend? I cannot use a SQL-Server based one for some reasons.

Comment: Can you not use SQL Server completely or would some kind of import from your access database to the wiki database be a good fit? If your wiki will be used by a lot of people I'm not sure if an access database would be an appropriate data store.

Answer (score 3):

For example **Open Wiki** can also be used with Access-Databases (MSDE):
http://www.openwiki.com/ow.asp?DownloadOpenWiki

Answer (score 3):

[Road Kill Wiki](http://roadkill.codeplex.com/) supports any DB engines NHibernate supports, [including MS Access](http://thoughtproject.com/Snippets/NHibernateWithAccess/index.htm).